# How to access current element index when iterating with iter() in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to loop over some alphabets here, printing single or multiple letters at once according to the value of the current letter.
Also skipping 3 letters (with `next()`) in case of C as shown, that's why I'm using `iter()` on the second line

```
alp = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
alpiter = iter(alp)
for i in range(len(alpiter)):
    if alpiter[i] == 'J':
        print(alp[i:i+3])
        # or print(alpiter[i:i+3]) not sure
    elif i == 'C':
        for l in range(3):
            next(alpiter)
    print(i)
```

BUT -*always a but*-, this code gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i in range(len(alpiter)):
TypeError: object of type 'str_iterator' has no len()
```

Apparently, iterable objects returned by `iter()` have no length.

I found this workaround by using a counter variable:

```
alp = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
alpiter = iter(alp)
cn  = 0
for i in alpiter:
    if i == 'J':
        print(alp[cn:cn+3])
    elif i == 'C':
        for l in range(3):
            next(alpiter)
            cn += 1
    print(i)
    cn += 1
```

My question; is there a native *pythonic* way to access the index of the current element while using `iter()` in a `for` loop? Without the counter of course.

Comment: The usual way in Python to get an index while iterating is to iterate over `enumerate()`'s output, instead of the original iterable.

Comment: @jasonharper does `enumerate()` has a built-in method to skip multiple iterations at once? like `next()`?

Comment: `iter(enumerate(X))` and `iter(X)` give you iterator objects with the same functionality - the only difference is that `next()` now gives you a (index, value) tuple rather than just the value.  In either case, the only way to skip forward is to call `next()` multiple times.

Comment: @jasonharper Aha! I see. I guess this answers my question. Thanks man